# 2011 AIME Problem 12, probability round table

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Nine delegates, three each from three different countries, randomly select chairs at a round table that seats nine people. Let the probability that each delegate sits next to at least one delegate from another country be $\frac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m+n$.

I have been searching around math stackexchange and I saw this difficult question, so I decided to try to work it out myself.

**Question:** I am numbering the chairs from (top to last) as $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.

Now I am stuck, how many ways are there TOTAL to arrange the people?

We want $P = 1 - P(\overbrace{\text{at least one block is the same or all three.}}^{x}) = 1 - P(x).$

The denominator is: $\binom{9}{3, 3, 3}$.This is the number of ways to make three groups of three objects in each.

Next: **How many ways are there to make one block identical eg. $AAA$?**

But for each $AAA$ there are three cases. Fix $a$ on chair 1 then there are possibilities: $AAa, aAA, AaA$. Thus for the $A$ there are: $3\binom{6}{3, 3}$ ways to arrange at least one block. Same for $B, C$ hence, $9\binom{6}{3, 3}$ total.

But in this we counted the $AAABBBCCC$ arrangements several times. For each $AAA$ there are two possible $AAABBBCCC$ sequences. So subtract $2(9) = 18$.

Hence:

$P = 1 - \frac{9\binom{6}{3, 3} - 18}{\binom{9}{3, 3, 3}} = \frac{253}{280}$

**WRONG answer.** I am confused, what I did wrong?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891601/2011-aime-problem-12-probability-9-delegates-around-a-round-table

Comment: Can you please explain how $27$ people fit into $9$ seats?

Comment: @barakmanos, wait when did I put 27 people?

Comment: "Nine delegates, three each": $9\cdot3=27$.

Comment: @barakmanos, I still don't understand

Comment: Me neither. "Nine delegates, three each", as far as I understand means "$9$ delegates, $3$ each", which comes down to a total of $27$ people.

Comment: @barakmanos, I meant nine total, $3$ of each race.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1399651/75923)

Comment: @drhab, I think I sort of got it. $9$ choices for $A$. Then $1, 1$ for the next $A$'s. Then, $\binom{6}{3, 3}$ for the $B, C$'s. But the same can be for $BBB, CCC$ so: $3 \cdot 9 \cdot \binom{6}{3, 3}$.

Comment: You need to first make up your mind whether you are going to treat people as distinct or clusters of 3, and make all computations in line with your choice.

Comment: You start with numbering chairs. In that context I would *not* fix chair $1$ for an $A$. Then there are $9\binom{6}{3,3}$ ways to place the $A$'s next to eachother. This on $\binom{9}{3,3,3}$ possibilities in total. So the probability that this will occur is $\frac3{28}$. Of course you have the same probabilities for blocks $BBB$ and $CCC$ and must use inclusion/exclusion to find the real answer. Btw, do you understand my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1399681/75923) on the question? To find out what someone did wrong is often more difficult than answering the question itself.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "at least one block is the same or all three"?

Comment: @drhab, but why do we subtract :$3 \cdot 9 \cdot 4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup we have $\binom9{3,3,3}=1680$ possibilities in total.

Let $n(A)$ denote the number of possibilities such that you have a block $AAA$. Likewise we use notations $n(B)$ and $n(C)$. Then $n(A)=n(B)=n(C)=9\binom6{3,3}=180$.

Let $n(A\cap B)$ denote the number of possibilities s.t. there is a block $AAA$ *and* a block $BBB$. Then $n(A\cap B)=n(A\cap C)=n(B\cap C)=9\times4=36$

Let $n(A\cap B\cap C)$ denote the number of possibilities s.t. there is a block $AAA$, a block $BBB$ *and* a block $CCC$. Then $n(A\cap B\cap C)=9\times2=18$

Finally let $n(A\cup B\cup C)$ denote the number of possibilitis such that there is block $AAA$ *or* a block $BBB$ *or* a block $CCC$.

With [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) we find:

$$n(A\cup B\cup C)=n(A)+n(B)+n(C)-n(A\cap B)-n(A\cap C)-n(B\cap C)+n(A\cap B\cap C)=3\times180-3\times36+18=450$$

So there is probability of $\frac{450}{1680}=\frac{15}{56}$ that there is at least one block and a probability of $\frac{41}{56}$ that there is no block.

The numbers $41$ and $56$ are coprime, so the final answer is $41+56=97$.

Hints for another setup can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1399681/75923).

Comment: (+1) I am a little confused regarding the multinomial coefficient in these cases. With: $$\binom{9}{3,3, 3}$$  This means the numbers of ways to arrange three groups of three objects each. Does this for example consider: $(AAA)(BCB)(CBC)$ for example?

Comment: I am no sure to understand your the question posed in the comment. The coefficient is the number of $9$-letter words that contain $3$ A's, $3$ B's and $3$ C's. The word in your comment is (if you remove the brackets) indeed one of these words. I don't see the relevance of the brackets.

Comment: My question was as you see what N.Hales said here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403100/why-do-we-subtract-combinatorics/1403423 ,  he said we subtract the four (written in his answer). But in reality, Don't we also need to subtract configurations such as: $AAABCBCBC$ from the $3 \cdot 9 \cdot \binom{6}{3, 3}$. **Moreover** What does $\binom{6}{3, 3}$ even represent? We begin with $AAA$, then the $3, 3$ means how many possible two blocks of three elements each right? If yes, then $AAABCBCBC$ is also included in that correct?

Comment: After adding up $n(A),n(B)$ and $n(C)$ we need to subtract configurations that are counted *more than once*. E.g. configuration $AAACBBBCC$ is one of them. This because there is a block $AAA$ in it (so counted under $n(A)$) and there is a block $BBB$ in it (so counted under $n(B)$). Configuration $AAABCBCBC$ *not* one of them. $\binom6{3,3}$ equals the number of $6$-letter words containing $3$ B's and $3$ C's. It comes in when $3$ of the original $9$ spots are allready possessed by an $AAA$ block.

Comment: okay it is starting to make more sense now, but how is $AAACBBBCC$ a configuration counted more than once? So: $n_1(a) = AAACBBBCC$ and $n_1(b) = AAACBBBCC$ too? Then is: $BBBCAAACC$ overcounted twice as well?

Comment: Yes $BBBCAAACC$ is counted twice. This because there is a block $AAA$ in it (so counted under $n(A))$ and a block $BBB$ in it (so counted under $n(B)$). Exactly the same is true for $AAACBBBCC$. By subtracting $n(A\cap B)$ these overcountings are "repaired". You should take a good look at the link to inclusion/exclusion on Wikipedia.

Comment: Without using the formula to explain these things. We have to begin with, $3 \cdot 9 \cdot \binom{6}{3, 3}$. This was for at least one block of something eg $AAA$. So in one we also have $AAACBBBCC$ for example and in another with $BBB$, we have again $AAACBBBCC$ So there it is twice. Then the ones with two of the blocks we have for one (AAA, BBB) that, $AAACBBBCC$. Then we have now, Total: $2 - 1 = 1$ final block of $AAACBBBCC$ no overcounting anymore. But why add back the $2(9)$?

Comment: We have dealt with the counting of figurations having exactly one block in it and also with those having exactly $2$ blocks in it. Now look at those with $3$ blocks in it. $AAABBBCCC$ and $CAAABBBCC$ are examples (note that here $CCC$ is a block because they are sitting at a round table). First they are counted $3$ times (this under $n(A),n(B)$ and $n(C)$). Then they are subtracted $3$ times (this under $n(A\cap B),n(A\cap C)$ and $n(B\cap C)$. So at that stage they are counted $3-3=0$ times. This is repaired by adding up $n(A\cap B\cap C)=18$.

Comment: I want to get one thing straight. Why not add just $9$?

Comment: There are in total $9$ configurations of the form $AAABBBCCC$ and there are $9$ configurations of the form $AAACCCBBB$. So $n(A\cap B\cap C)=2\times9$.

Comment: thank you for all your help, this question is way more clear now. I have an interesting question. In the beginning we decided the total ways to arrange was: $\binom{9}{3, 3, 3}$. Why not $\binom{9}{4, 3}$ it is the same thing isn't it?

Comment: There is nothing whatsoever that stimulates me to start with $\binom{9}{4,3}$. The same thing? In what sense? I really do not understand your thinking here. Something else: only  write $(+1)$ in a comment to an answer if you indeed upvote that answer.

Comment: Okay. What configurations does $\binom{9}{3, 3, 3}$ include that $\binom{9}{4, 3}$ excludes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27265/discussion-between-drhab-and-amad27).

Answer (score 1):

You got the total probability right.
Now regarding the numerator. (I would like to note that in your solution, you regarded the delegates from each country to be indistinguishable). We need to find the number of ways that *each* delegate sits next to at least one delegate from another country

The number of ways to make one block identical is actually not what you have. Suppose you have AAA as one block. Then the other six delegates can be arranged in $\binom{6}{3, 3}$ ways. However, you *do not* arrange the 3 delegates inside the AAA block. Instead, you can put the AAA block in any of the 9 chairs. So we have $9\times \binom{6}{3, 3}$ ways to have an AAA block. So the number of ways to have an identical block is $3 \times 9\times \binom{6}{3, 3}=27\times 20.$

We now need the number of ways for candidates from *two* countries to each sit together. We can do this in $3\times9\times4=27\times4$ ways. (I believe this is the part you didn't calculate)

Finally we need the number of ways that the candidates from all countries sit together. This can be done in $9\times2=18$ ways, one clockwise and the other anticlockwise.

So the total number of unwanted arrangements is $27\times20-27\times4+18.$

This should lead you to the right answer (I don't know the answer because the AOPS site seems to be down, but I got $m+n$ to be $97.$)

Comment: (+1). A little confused though, how did you get $3 \times 9 \times 4$ ways for the candidates from two countries to sit together? I see that there are for example, $9$ ways to arrange the $AAA$ Then the possibilities are: $BCBCBC, CBCBCB, BBBCCC, CCCBBB$.  So these are the four?

Comment: The answer is correct.