# Why do we subtract [Combinatorics]

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I asked [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402463/2011-aime-problem-12-probability-round-table) This question and I am still confused. I got that, for at least one group together there are:

$$3 \cdot 9 \cdot \binom{6}{3, 3}$$

But why do we subtract: $3 \cdot 9 \cdot 4$.

Lets begin with $AAA$ suppose circularly. (We multiply by $3$ in the end for $BBB, CCC$ so not to worry about that). There are $9$ possible places for $AAA$. I saw that: $BCBCBC, CBCBCB$ are two already. Then :$BBCBCC, BCBBCC$, etcc... that is more than $4$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Number theory? Probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an arrangement like $AAACBBBCC$, with exactly two blocks of delegates sitting together. The figure

$$3\cdot9\cdot\binom{6}{3,3}\tag{1}$$

counts that arrangement twice, once for the $AAA$ block and once for the $BBB$ block. In fact, *every* arrangement that has two blocks gets counted twice in $(1)$, so $(1)$ is definitely an overcount. How many of these arrangements are there that we’ve counted twice?

There are $\binom32=3$ ways to choose $2$ countries whose candidates will all sit together. Pick the first of these two countries in alphabetical order: there are $9$ possible positions at the table for their block. That leaves $6$ open seats, and the block for the other chosen country can be placed in any of $4$ positions within that string of $6$ seats. Thus, there are

$$3\cdot9\cdot4\tag{2}$$ arrangements with two blocks of $3$ delegates sitting together. In $(1)$ we’ve counted each of those arrangements twice, once for each of the two blocks, so we need to subtract $3\cdot9\cdot4$ from $(1)$ to compensate for the original overcounting.

But we’re still not quite done, because of arrangements like $AAABBBCCC$ in which all *three* countries have their candidates seated together. Each of these arrangements is counted $3$ times in $(1)$, once for each block. Each of these arrangements is also counted $3$ times in $(2)$, once for each *pair* of blocks: there are $\binom32=3$ pairs of blocks. Thus, in

$$3\cdot9\cdot\binom{6}{3,3}-3\cdot9\cdot4$$

each of these arrangements has been counted $3-3=0$ times. We therefore need to make a final correction: we need to add back in the number of such arrangments. There are $9$ choices of position for country $A$’s block. Once $A$’s block has been seated, there are $2$ possible choices of position for country $B$’s block, and country $C$’s block must then take what’s left. Thus, there are $9\cdot2$ arrangements in which all three sets of delegates are sitting in blocks, and the final correction gives us a total of

$$3\cdot9\cdot\binom{6}{3,3}-3\cdot9\cdot4+9\cdot2$$

arrangements with at least one country’s candidates sitting together.

This is an example of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: But BBBCAAACC is a different arrangement though? (+1)

Comment: @Amad27: I’m not sure what you’re asking; different from what?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott AAACBBBCC, the first arrangement you mentioned.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Yes, it's different even if you put the AAA blocks in the same seats, so that you're comparing AAACBBBCC and AAACCBBBC: the two arrangements are reversals of each other.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Then why do you say overcounting?

Comment: @Amad27: Because $(1)$ counts AAACBBBCC once for the block AAA and once for the block BBB, so it counts that one arrangement twice. It also counts AAACCBBBC once for the block AAA and once again for the block BBB, so that arrangement also gets counted twice. Thus, these two arrangements, which should contribute $2$ to the total, end up contributing $4$, an overcount of $2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I wrote elsewhere too, but: Without using the formula to explain these things. We have to begin with, $3⋅9⋅\binom{6}{3, 3}$. This was for at least one block of something eg AAA. So in one we also have AAACBBBCC for example and in another with BBB, we have again AAACBBBCC So there it is twice. Then the ones with two of the blocks we have for one (AAA, BBB) that, AAACBBBCC. Then we have now, Total: 2−1=1 final block of AAACBBBCC no overcounting anymore. But why add back the 2(9)?

Comment: @Amad27: Because AAABBBCCC, AABBBCCCA, ABBBCCCAA, BBBCCCAAA, BBCCCAAAB, BCCCAAABB, CCCAAABBB, CCAAABBBC, CAAABBBCC, AAACCCBBB, AACCCBBBA, ACCCBBBAA, CCCBBBAAA, CCBBBAAAC, CBBBAAACC, BBBAAACCC, BBAAACCCB, and BAAACCCBB are first counted $3$ times each in $(1)$, but then each of them is also counted $3$ times in $(2)$. Take AAABBBCCC, for instance. It’s counted once for AAA, once for BBB, and once for CCC in $(1)$, but it’s also counted once for AAA & BBB, once for AAA & CCC, and once for BBB & CCC in $(2)$. Thus, it’s not counted at all after the first subtraction, so it has to be added back in

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I am sorry for being a bother. But how is $ABBBCCCAA$ counted three times in $(1)$? We broke (1) into three cases: $AAA, BBB, CCC$. So If we have $BBB$ then: $ABBBCCCAA$ is achievable. If we have $CCC$ then: $ABBBCCCAA$ is achievable again. But not with $AAA$, so how three?

Comment: @Amad27: You’re forgetting that the table is circular: in ABBBCCCAA the three delegates from country A *are* sitting together, so the arrangement is counted three times. It’s the same arrangement as AAABBBCCC after everyone moves two seats to the left.

Answer (score 0):

To directly address the issue you seem to be having: the arrangements with at least *two* blocks of 3 delegates are the following:

1. $AAABBBCCC$
2. $AAACBBBCC$
3. $AAACCBBBC$
4. $AAACCCBBB$

for the specific case of *at least* the delegates from countries $A$ and $B$ sitting sitting in blocks of 3 (there are also 4 arrangements where the two blocks are the $A$s and $C$s and where they are the $B$s and $C$s).

From what you have written it seems as if you have forgotten that for the count 3⋅9⋅4 we must have *two* blocks of 3 delegates. Therefore arrangements like $BCBCBC$ or $CBCBCB$ as you mention in your question do not count as they don't fulfil this requirement, only those 4 listed here do.

You can also see that 1 and 4 in this list contribute to those cases where at least 3 blocks of 3 delegates sit together. These 2 cases are each counted 3⋅9 times in the figure 3⋅9⋅4 and 3⋅9 times in the figure 3⋅9⋅$\binom{6}{3,3}$ thus cancelling them out. That is why they are added back at the end in the 9⋅2 term.

Comment: But why doesnt $BCBCBC$ for example count to subtract from the overall?

Comment: That particular arrangement *is* subtracted in the  3⋅9 ⋅$\binom{6}{3,3}$ term since it has a block of $AAA$ (not shown). The same is true for $CBCBCB$ and all other arrangements with a single block of 3 delegates. All of those types of arrangements don't appear in the  3⋅9⋅4 or  9⋅2 terms because they count arrangements with *at least* 2 and 3 block of 3 delegates respectively. Please check out the link others have provided on inclusion-exclusion as I feel this may help clarify with the aid of a Venn Diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your specific doubt has been cleared. Here I only want to tell you that when *probability* has been asked for, whether you take people in a group as distinct and chairs as numbered, or not, it won't affect the answer. You can choose as may be convenient for the problem.

A solution with *people* taken as distinct, but the chairs as unnumbered, can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891601/2011-aime-problem-12-probability-9-delegates-around-a-round-table?lq=1)

For comparison, the two solutions are summarised below:

*[ I ]: Chairs numbered, but only the groups distinct*

$\displaystyle 1-\frac{\binom{3}{1}\cdot9{6\choose 3,3}-\binom{3}{2}\cdot9\cdot4 +{3\choose 3}\cdot9\cdot 2}{9\choose 3,3,3}=\frac{41}{56}$

*[ II ]: Chairs unnumbered, but people distinct*

$\displaystyle 1-\frac{\binom{3}{1}3!6!-\binom{3}{2}4(3!)^{3}+2(3!)^{3}}{8!}=\frac{41}{56}$