# Probabilities in circular arrangements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For computing probability for a circular arrangement, it should not matter whether we take people in a group as distinct and chairs as numbered, or not, and we should be able to choose as per our convenience. Such a question is 2011 AIME Problem 12

> Nine delegates, three each from three different countries, randomly select chairs at a round table that seats nine people. Let the probability that each delegate sits next to at least one delegate from another country be $\frac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m+n$.

Two solutions (obtained by others, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403100/why-do-we-subtract-combinatorics/1403557#1403557) and link given therein) were:

*[ I ]: Chairs numbered, but only the groups distinct*

$\displaystyle 1-\frac{\binom{3}{1}\cdot9{6\choose 3,3}-\binom{3}{2}\cdot9\cdot4 +{3\choose 3}\cdot9\cdot 2}{9\choose 3,3,3}=\frac{41}{56}$

*[ II ]: Chairs unnumbered, but people distinct*

$\displaystyle 1-\frac{\binom{3}{1}3!6!-\binom{3}{2}4(3!)^{3}+2(3!)^{3}}{8!}=\frac{41}{56}$

I then tried to work out a solution with chairs unnumbered and only groups distinct, i.e. *[ I ]* modified with chairs unnumbered.

For the numerator in the fractional part, it should suffice to just factor out the 9.

*The problem I face is that to get the same answer, the denominator needed is fractional. So where is the error in my working ?*

$\displaystyle 1-\frac{\binom{3}{1}{6\choose 3,3}-\binom{3}{2}\cdot4 +{3\choose 3}\cdot 2}{???}=\frac{41}{56}$

Comment: Something doesn't seem to be right, since letting the denominator be $d$ and solving gives $1-\frac{50}{d}=\frac{41}{56}$ so $d=\frac{560}{3}$.

Comment: @user84413: That is the question ! If something is not right, what is it ? Pl. note that I have edited the question to pose the problem more clearly.

Comment: @Brian Tung: It is not a duplicate. The answer has been worked out in various ways already, I am asking how to work it out treating seats as unnumbered and only groups as distinct, because I am facing a difficulty, and can't understand where the mistake lies.

Comment: It's a good question, and I am just saying that the numerator can't be right, apparently.

Comment: Yes, but if answer [ I ] is right, and we have  factored out the 9 multiplier in the numerator so as to treat seats as unnumbered, what else needs to be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see why this method doesn't work, consider the simpler case where we have 3 people from 2 countries each, and we want to find the probability that each delegate sits next to at least one person from the other country.

$\textbf{1)}$ If we consider the people distinct and the chairs unnumbered, we get

$P(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})=1-[P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)]=1-\frac{2(3!)^2-(3!)^2}{5!}=1-\frac{36}{120}=\frac{7}{10}$.

$\textbf{2)}$ If we consider the people from each country the same and the chairs numbered, there are

$\binom{6}{3}=20$ ways to seat the people and 6 ways to seat them with 3 people from the same country together,

so this gives a probability of $1-\frac{6}{20}=\frac{7}{10}$.

---

However, if we consider the people from each country the same and the chairs unnumbered,

there are only 4 possible arrangements of the people,

and 3 of these arrangements have each delegate next to a delegate  from another country.

The probability is $\textbf{not}$ equal to $\frac{3}{4}$, though, since these possibilities are not equally likely.

[Three of these arrangements each correspond to 6 of the 20 seatings in case $\textbf{2)}$,

while the fourth arrangement only corresponds to 2 of these seatings.]

Comment: I think that it is not that a probability of $\frac34$ is *incorrect*, it is *different* because the permutations become those of "necklaces". But who is going to count necklaces of 3 colors !

Comment: @trueblueanil You're right that these are now necklaces being considered. (I just meant that this isn't the correct probability for the question being asked.)  You also had the correct numerator of 50; I was mistaken in thinking that it must be wrong.